# Get details of device connected to a network

Tags: wireless, arp, ping, network-discovery

I am trying to detect if a netcam is connected to my network on an Android app. To do so, I have found that I need to ping every IP on the network in order to get the active devices or somehow send an ARP request. The problem is that this only gets the IP and MAC address of the device, and I would like to get some more details like the manufacturer and model, for instance. How can I do so programmatically?

There is certainly something network related that I'm not understanding because this does not appear to be a problem to some networking tools like Fing for Android, which are able to get all details on every device on a network. How do they do it?

I do not require a code answer, a theoretical answer should suffice.

Comment: I'd say, it depends (also about what "all details" means). Based on the MAC address, you can find out the vendor of the device. OS detection can be done using, e.g. fingerprinting or based on running services - maybe look at the description of [nmap](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html).

Comment: I don't need all details, just the manufacturer would be a big start, and OS would also be very nice. How can I infer the vendor just by the MAC address? Wouldn't that require a huge table of MAC addresses and vendor names? Also, if you consider adding some more information (as an answer) I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: In fact, there is such a "huge" table ;-) (see my answer)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: This was an old question that I forgot about. It was indeed answered, and I have now accepted the best answer for this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the vendor of the NIC from the [OUI database](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt).

Comment: This is way too big to fit on an Android app (3,5MB just for the file). Is there any web-service or something similar that can allow me to query this database? BTW, the Fing application takes up 2,83MB for everything, so I believe they are querying it remotely somehow.

Comment: I found a smaller version on the Wireshark website [here](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf).

Comment: you submit it on http://coffer.com/mac_find/ and scrape the answer

Comment: It's written on the page that the last update was in July, 2013. I am unable to query for my computer's mac address.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pinging every single device, you could ping the broadcast address, and all devices would reply. For example, if you are on a 192.168.0.0/24 network, your broadcast address would be 192.168.0.255. Then all devices would send out an ARP reply. From here you could run a port scan on the specific IP address that the MAC in question is tied to. If you don't know the MAC address, you're going to have to do a scan on every device that replies.

Comment: Is this supposed to work on a command line? I can't get it to work: I ping the broadcast address and get nothing back out of the ordinary..

Comment: It should work just fine from any device that can ping. And has an arp table. Once you ping the broadcast, check the arp table for new entries.

Comment: I forgot to check the arp table. It does indeed work. However, when the device I'm looking for gets disconnected, the ARP table does not reflect that change: the device continues listed. Is this a normal behaviour and if so, why?

Comment: To see the change, you would have to flush your ARP cache and ping the broadcast address again to update it. This is normal behavior, ARP is essentially agnostic of other device's link-state and a device will stay in the arp cache until it is cleared again, or another device sends an ARP reply using the same IP as the previous device.

Comment: Why is the port scan going to be necessary? If StephenKing's info is correct, can't I just get the MAC address with the ARP reply and use it to check the manufacturer in the OUI database?

Comment: You sure can use the OUI DB, the port scan isn't required for that information, but could possibly give you more information about the devices you are looking at, such as which services those devices may offer.

Comment: How hard would it be to perform a port scan once I have the MAC address? What is required / how is it done?

Comment: You don't perform a port scan on a MAC address, it is performed at layers 3 and up. It is performed on a device's IP address. Nmap seems to be a popular one, but there are many others. OSX has one built in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26695/discussion-between-aprendiz-and-chris-cummings).

Answer (score 1):

Fing, Angry IP, netstat and arp -a are good starters...and depending on whether you have access to the infrastructure you can check the dhcp scope and issuance...along with CDP or LLDP on the networking equipment.

Fing though its good!